# Recover the source file name in a Shake rule

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I am writing a build system for a static website which works like this:

- for every file `src/123-some-title.txt` produce a file `out/123.html`

My problem is that when writing the rule for `out/*.html` I have no direct way to recover the source file name (`src/123-some-title.txt`) from the target file name (`out/123.html`).

Of course I could read the `src/` directory again and search for a file that starts with `123`, but is there a nicer way to do this with Shake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to mention is that if you call `getDirectoryFiles` multiple times with the same arguments it will only calculate once, in the same way that if you call `need` multiple times on the same file it will only build once. One approach would be:

```
"out/*.fwd" *> \out -> do
    res <- getDirectoryFiles "src" ["*.txt"]
    let match = [(takeBaseName out ++ "-") `isPrefixOf` takeBaseName x  | x <- res]
    when (length match /= 1) $ error "fail, because wrong number of matches"
    writeFileChanged out $ head match

"out/*.html" *> \out -> do
    src <- readFile' (out -<.> "fwd")
    txt <- readFile' ("src" </> src)
    ...
```

Here the idea is that the file `out/123.txt` contain the contents `123-some-title.txt`. By using `writeFileChanged` we only change the `.fwd` file when the relevant part of the directory changes.

If you want to avoid the `.fwd` files, you can use the `Oracle` mechanism. If you want to avoid a linear scan of the `getDirectoryFiles` result you can use the `newCache` function. In practice, neither is likely to be problematic, and going with the files is probably simplest.